# how can I link two models in dbt?

Tags: model, hyperlink, dbt, vault

suppose you have two models in vault - and these models have a mutual fields

so, how could I link them in dbt ? any example - link - videos etc.

thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your question. Please provide an example of your models. I'm not understanding how what you're seeking differs from a standard SQL JOIN.

Comment: I have two models in raw-vault so that represents historical data in snowflake, two of them has a connection to each other but in dbt i need an entity to "link" them together. which is not a sql query, it's another object to identify the relationship between hashkeys.